# CRUD Operation in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started Angular2. I want to create CRUD App in angular2, I searched on net and I found many but all were outdated. Can any one provide me link to get started with CRUD operation Angular2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best way to learn Angular 2 is to follow official documentation.
First, finish the [5 Min Quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). Then follow [The Hero Editor tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) which is basically a tutorial for creating CRUD application with some other very useful components, such as routing, which is essential to any application you might create in future. After completing this, you can try to create your own CRUD application to check if you got a hang of things in Angular 2.

Answer (score 4):

Angular 2 official documentation is good choice but I found https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/categories/angular2-step-by-step/ interesting and easy to understand.

Comment: Usefull link to learn